# JavaScript to Flash and Back?

Tags: javascript, flash

I am completely new to flash.  We need to load a binary file from the user system (must work in Flash 9) and do some process in flash and save it back to the file system. I think that this would have to be done by getting the file in JavaScript and then encoding it send it to Flash.

Comment: The internets seem to imply to me accessing arbitrary local files is only available in Flash 10.

Comment: yes, now I am using flash 10 for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local file system access is in [Flash 10](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/features/) with the [File Reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html) enhancements. You're out of luck if targetting Flash 9.

Javascript cannot access the local filesystem either.

Answer (score 1):

http://weblogs.macromedia.com/flashjavascript/
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/156/tn_15683.html

Those are two good links reguarding javascript communications

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can make a JavaScript Flash file and make a window SWF, which has full file access. However, this could never be used on the web